# how to move mesh object in react three js using arrow keys?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

this is my app.js file and here i used THREE js to create a 3d BOX.

```
const Box = () => {
    // --> https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry

    return (
        <mesh position={[0, 0, 5]}>
            <boxBufferGeometry attach='geometry' args={[1, 1, 1]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="#CF1F55" />
        </mesh>
    )
}
```

now i am trying to move this box using arrow keys - up, down, left, right.

i tried to do this using this. but it is not working.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e)
    {
        if(e.key === 'ArrowUp')
        {
            Car.Box.position.z -= 1;
    
        }
        else if(e.key === 'ArrowDown')
        {
            Car.Box.position.z += 1;
        }
        else if(e.key === 'ArrowLeft')
        {
            Car.Box.position.x -= 1;
        }
        else if(e.key === 'ArrowRight')
        {
            Car.Box.position.x += 1;
        }
        console.log(e);
    }
```

but it is not working.
any idea how to move this box. please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of framework beyond core three.js, like React? Please include a tag for that framework, as there may be other considerations on that side for making this work.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes. react. will use the tag.